# How to creat a mouse Resistance to a Div like a Magnet effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I created a circle and i want him to move when the mouse is near like a Magnet effect (so the elements i'll put under him will get exposed).

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cfsamet/5xFVc/1/

some starting code:

```
$('#circle').mouse(function(){
    $(this).();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `Perimeter.js (http://github.e-sites.nl/perimeter.js/)`.
This does exactly what you want to do.